# How to fulfill a promise with Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, promise, nightwatch.js

I am switching from Protractor to Nightwatch.js, and I am facing some difficulties with the way Nightwatch handles the promises.

To give an example, I am trying to count the number of element satisfying a given criterion. The count function is in a page object, so separated from the test itself:

The page object command:

```
    countToDoList: function(browser) {
        browser.elements('css selector', "input[ng-model='todo.done']", function(result){
            return result.value.length;
        });
    }
```

and the call in the test:

```
'Angular - 1' : function(browser) {
  var angular = browser.page.angularPO();
  var mainPage = angular.section.main;

  angular.openMainPage(browser);
  var countToDoBoxes = 0;

  countToDoBoxes = mainPage.countToDoList(browser);
  console.log("countToDoBoxes = " + countToDoBoxes);

  browser.end();
}
```

This returns "countToDoBoxes = undefined". And based on my (short) experience with Protractor, I assume that this is due to the function not fulfilling the promise, when it's passed to "countToDoBoxes".

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: If you expect `browser.elements` to return a promise, then you should probably use `.then()` instead of passing the callback directly. Also, you'd obviously have to `return` from the `countToDoList` method.

Comment: Just for my own interest, why are you switching?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper : I work on a different project, and this new one works with Nightwatch.js (not my choice, and can't change that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find the API description for `elements`, however here is your code, modified to return a Bluebird promise. (You could do something similar with the Promise library of your choice.)

```
countToDoList: function(browser) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        browser.elements('css selector', "input[ng-model='todo.done']", function(result){
            resolve(result.value.length);
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You could make it into one by showing an example of how that code would work using a promise.

Comment: @StefanHanke Please review my (now modified) response to the OP's question and verify that it meets your expectations. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Looks fine for me now. Thanks! See [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements) for the elements call to the NightwatchJS API (unfortunately the docs are... not very useful actually). The [JWP](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/elements) is more useful.

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry for the late answer, I only see your edited answer now. I didn't know Promises could be created this way with Nightwatch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to answer the question you have, instead, I'll show a solution to the problem you have. I think this will help Googlers who've come here trying to use promises with Nightwatch as well.

Firstly, Nightwatch doesn't have a promise-based API, it uses callbacks. If you try to use promises with Nightwatch it'll be painful because you're moving against its programming paradigm.

So what I think should do is, firstly, modify the `countToDoList` function so it receives a callback function. Call it with the value you've derived.

It's also important that you return `browser` so we can chain something after this.

```
countToDoList: function(browser, callback) {
  return browser.elements('css selector', "input[ng-model='todo.done']", function(result){
    callback(result.value.length);
  });
}
```

Now, in your test, use the callback in `countToDoList` to assign a value to `countToDoBoxes`. You'll then need to chain the `perform` method. This method ensures that whatever you put in its callback is added to the end of Nightwatch's command queue. Now you can be sure you'll have the value of `countToDoBoxes` available when you try to log it.

```
'Angular - 1' : function(browser) {
  var angular = browser.page.angularPO();
  var mainPage = angular.section.main;

  angular.openMainPage(browser);
  let countToDoBoxes;

  mainPage
    .countToDoList(browser, function(count) {
      countToDoBoxes = count;
    })
    .perform(function() {
      console.log("countToDoBoxes = " + countToDoBoxes);
    })
    .end();
}
```

By the way, this is all explained in the article [Understanding the Command Queue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue) which for some unknown reason is not directly in the Nightwatch docs where I think it belongs.